# Test SafeHtml pipe for string to be sanitized

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I would like test if unsafe string was wrapped in `SafeHtml` object

This is my SafeHtmlPipe

```
@Pipe({ name: "safehtml" })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

SafeHtml spec

```
describe('SafeHtmlPipe', () => {
    let sanitizer;
    let pipe: SafeHtmlPipe;
    const unsafeHtml = `<a href="javascript:alert('XSS')">Unsafe</a>`;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [BrowserModule]
        });

        sanitizer = TestBed.get(DomSanitizer);
        pipe = new SafeHtmlPipe(sanitizer);

    });

    it('should create an instance', () => {
        expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should transform html to SafeHtml', () => {
        let safeHtml = pipe.transform(unsafeHtml);
        // check if unsafe html wrapped in SafeHtml object
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? The `DomSanitizer` will *always* return a `SafeHtml` value - no matter what the input.

Comment: @Anton the idea is to make sure that pipe returns `SafeHtml` in case that in future some one might change the pipe